# Unsupported field value: undefined,Function addDoc() called with invalid data

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

so here I want to store the array of image URL from the firebase storage in firestore. I am getting an error of undefined as my ImageUrl is undefined. please help me to solve this.The images are stored on cloud storage.
The code below shows my onSubmit function where a copy of the formdata is created.I have tried with and without '.then' and both gives me this error

```
const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    if (discountedPrice >= regularPrice) {
      setLoading(false);
      toast.error("Discounted price should be less than regular price");
    }
    console.log(formData);
    if (images.length > 6) {
      setLoading(false);
      toast.error("Max of 6 images");
    }
    let geolocation = {};
    let location;
    // if (address != null) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${address}&key=${process.env.React_App_YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY}`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      geolocation.lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      geolocation.lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
      console.log(
        "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
      );
      console.log(geolocation.lat);
      console.log(data.status);
      location =
        data.status == "ZERO_RESULTS"
          ? undefined
          : data.results[0].formatted_address;
      if (location == undefined || location.includes("undefined")) {
        setLoading(false);
        toast.error("area does not match");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("area does not match");
    }

    //s store image to firebase
    const storeImage = async (image) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const storage = getStorage();
        const fileName = `${auth.currentUser.uid}-${image.name}-${uuidv4()}`;

        const storageRef = ref(storage, "images/" + fileName);
        const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, image);

        uploadTask.on(
          "state_changed",
          (snapshot) => {
            // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
            // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
            const progress =
              (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
            switch (snapshot.state) {
              case "paused":
                console.log("Upload is paused");
                break;
              case "running":
                console.log("Upload is running");
                break;
            }
          },
          (error) => {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            reject(error);
          },
          () => {
            // Handle successful uploads on complete
            // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
            getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
              resolve(downloadURL);
              console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
            });
          }
        );
      });
    };

    const imageUrls = await Promise.all(
      [...images].map((image) => {
        storeImage(image);
      })
    )
      .then(() => {
        console.log("urlready " + imageUrls);
        uploadingListings(imageUrls);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setLoading(false);
        toast.error("Couldn't upload image");
        return;
      });

    const uploadingListings = async (imageUrls) => {
      console.log(imageUrls);
      const formDataCopy = {
        ...formData,
        imageUrls,
        geolocation,
        timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
      };
      formDataCopy.location = address;
      delete formDataCopy.address;
      delete formDataCopy.images;
      !formDataCopy.offer && delete formDataCopy.discountedPrice;
      console.log("this is" + formDataCopy);

      const docRef = await addDoc(
        collection(db, "listings"),
        formDataCopy
setLoading(false);
        toast.success("Created a listing");
        navigate(`/category/${formDataCopy.type}/${docRef.id}`);
      });
    };
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(formDataCopy)` and check if any field is `undefined`?

Comment: yes the imageUrls in undefined...Which I don't get why it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed it.
Realized I wasn't returning the url to imageUrls.
And also found it not helpful using the .then with imageUrls.

```
const imageUrls = await Promise.all(
      [...images].map((image) => {
        return storeImage(image);
      })
    )
      // .then(() => {
      //   console.log("urlready " + imageUrls);
      //   return uploadingListings(imageUrls);
      // })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setLoading(false);
        toast.error("Couldn't upload listing");
        return;
      });
      console.log("urlready " + imageUrls);
      const formDataCopy = {
        ...formData,
        imageUrls,
        geolocation,
        timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
      };
      console.log(formDataCopy);
      formDataCopy.location = address;
      delete formDataCopy.address;
      delete formDataCopy.images;
      !formDataCopy.offer && delete formDataCopy.discountedPrice;
      console.log("this is" + formDataCopy);

      const docRef = await addDoc(
        collection(db, "listings"),
        formDataCopy
      )
        console.log(docRef);
        setLoading(false);
        toast.success("Created a listing");
        navigate(`/category/${formDataCopy.type}/${docRef.id}`);
      
    
  };
```